Dynamic SQL Agent Parameter
I have added two parameters to a SSIS package. BeginDate and EndDate are hard-coded as 3/1/2024 and 3/31/2024.  In the corresponding SQL Agent Job, I can see the package parameters.  I would like to pass dynamic Previous Month Begin and Previous Month End parameters via the SQL Agent Job, instead of the hard-coded dates so that this can run on a monthly schedule without any intervention. If needed I can then change the dates temporarily to a two-month span for example.  I would like it to default to the previous month begin and previous month end SQL Agent Job parameters.



Thanks in advance.

If it will always be previous month in your variable in the SSIS package you can use an Expression to calculate the previous month inside the package, no need to use Agent Job to assign them.

Why not just set param default to NULL in procedure and then calculate the previous month things if param is NULL

A sql agent job, running an SSIS package as you show cannot have dynamic parameters like you want to do.
Instead, you need to change your job type from Integration Services to TSQL and instead you'll make the parameters dynamic there and then run the ssis package.
The content of your script will look something like the following
DECLARE @execution_id bigint;
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.create_execution
    @package_name = N'CheckMyBits.dtsx'
,   @execution_id = @execution_id OUTPUT
,   @folder_name = N'demo'
,   @project_name = N'SO_Trash'
,   @use32bitruntime = False
,   @reference_id = NULL
,   @runinscaleout = False;
SELECT
    @execution_id;

DECLARE @var0 sql_variant = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1);
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.set_execution_parameter_value
    @execution_id
,   @object_type = 20
,   @parameter_name = N'start_date'
,   @parameter_value = @var0;

DECLARE @var1 sql_variant = CAST(EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AS date);
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.set_execution_parameter_value
    @execution_id
,   @object_type = 20
,   @parameter_name = N'end_date'
,   @parameter_value = @var1;

DECLARE @var2 smallint = 1;
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.set_execution_parameter_value
    @execution_id
,   @object_type = 50
,   @parameter_name = N'LOGGING_LEVEL'
,   @parameter_value = @var2;
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.start_execution @execution_id;

You can see @var0 and @var1 are getting current month begin/end dates and assigning them to my package's parameters of start_date and end_date
